# How to make leather sneakers black again, but not shiny?

Tags: clothing, shoes

I have [these leather sneakers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TP9847I):

[image: ECCO Collin Classic Tie]

They are scuffed now, and in those regions the black has become a grayish worn color.  When I wipe these shoes with a damp cloth, they change to a nice black matte color like they were originally, but this wears off as they dry out again.

Is there something I can put on the shoes to make them stay like this?

It seems shoe polish is all about making shoes shiny, which I am not interested in.

I used to have the kind that behaves like black paint, which I am also not interested in, because it would blacken the white stitching.

Comment: If you live somewhere you can buy Punch Scuff kote, use that - covers up scuff marks really well, better than polish, isn't shiny unless you buff it.

Comment: @Bamboo "comes in Black, Brown and Navy."  So it's like the paint kind that I don't want?

Comment: Well its liquid - take the laces out before using if they're white, replace when they're dry. Can be cleaned off metal eyelets before its dry. But I'm confused - that picture you show does not have white laces, and it also looks as if the toe and heel inserts are suede rather than plain leather, though that may just be a trick of the light in the photo

Comment: @Bamboo I meant white stitching, not laces, sorry

Comment: Ah, well, then you've got a real problem... any blackening you use will cover the white stitching...

Comment: @Bamboo Yes, that's why I don't want blackening :D

Comment: But without anything that blackens, you can't make those scuffed areas black again...

Comment: @Bamboo Water makes them look black again.  There's nothing that moisturizes the surface or gives it a "damp look"?

Comment: I wonder if saddle soap would - comes in a jar for shoes, but I don't know for sure. Its meant to keep leather supple and prevent cracking, so its a sort of moisturizer

Comment: @Bamboo Amazon customer images look promising! https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71wxZDaDu6L.jpg  add that as an answer

Comment: worth a try then - but not really a hack!

Comment: @Bamboo Well you should add it as an answer anyway

Comment: @Bamboo Well I tried it and it worked pretty well, you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested saddle soap for shoes, which apparently has done the trick, but although I was asked to post this as an answer, it doesn't really count, because it's not a hack - a product had to be purchased to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

When I polished my own shoes as a kid, I remember that polish doesn't make your shoes shiny. Buffing them, with a cloth or a special brush, is what makes them shiny. So you should be able to apply polish to get that matte look, so long as you don't buff them.